Powershell Enter-PSSession command doesn't work in studio
I m new in PS stuff, I develop st in c#, that connect a remote machine and start a few exe for me.
I tried some ps code for connect and start an exe  in remote server. It s worked ok.
But i couldn't get same result in c#.
My ps code in c# worked ok in local operation.
this is my c# code
thanks for help!
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        SecureString pass = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "12345").SecurePassword;
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(@"user1", pass);
        
        ps.AddCommand("Enter-PSSession");
        ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", @"RemoteIP");
        ps.AddParameter("Credential", credential);

        ps.Invoke();


Enter-PSSession is for interactive use only - you need to either supply a custom host that implements IHostSupportsInteractiveSession or use Invoke-Command instead

Yeah thanks! its work for me

Thanks for answer. It's work for me but now , I have diffrent problem related this subject.
start-process in  Invoke command run related exe. But its closed by immadiatly by something. Its show up in task manager for just a second and closed before doing whats to be done.

As Mathias stated in the comments u can use invoke-command. Now there are two ways to do so: by using the -computername parameter for one time use or by creating a session and using the -session parameter:
$result= invoke-command -computername “nameOfClientToConnectTo” -scriptblock{
“Do something on this computer”}

$session= new-pssession -computername “nameOfClientToConnectTo”
  $result= invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock{
    “Do something on this computer”}

The scriptblock doesn’t know the variables u declare outside of it. So if u wanna work with them u Aamust hand them over via the -argumentlist parameter. U can also declare the scriptblock up front as variable which makes it very flexible to use especially in the combination with an argument list. I can provide another example for that if needed.

Good to hear that it works for u. Please accept answer create new question for new problem and put link in comment here so i can have a look at it, glad to help

Hi dome. I create a new post. Link is below. Thanks for helps!
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78772499/26422288
