PowerShell Start-Process in Invoke Command doesn't work correctly
I have a problem with PowerShell. Main goal is to run an exe (developed by me) on a remote machine.
start-process in Invoke the command run related an exe. But its closed immediately by something. It shows up in the task manager for just a few second and closes before doing what need to be done.
My PS code like this:
$passwd = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String "myPass"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "domain\user",$passwd
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverIP -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\b.ari\Desktop\myProgram.exe"} -Credential $cred


In remote commands based on Invoke-Command -ComputerName, any asynchronously launched processes in the remote session are forcefully terminated when the Invoke-Command call returns. Thus, you  need to ensure that the processes run synchronously, preferably by direct invocation or by passing -Wait to Start-Process. (Alternatively, create a longer-lived session explicitly with New-PSSession and pass it to Invoke-Command -Session, which allows you to check for completion later.) See the linked duplicate for details.

Take off the quotes and you don't even need start-process.
